# Qt Creator. Как установить библиотеку Phonon?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть необходимость в использовании этой библиотеки. 
При добавлении строки `QT += phonon` в .pro файл - выдает ошибку:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: phonon

ОС Ubuntu 16.04. Версия Qt: 5.7.0
Использую Qt Creator 4.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При переходе с Qt 4 на Qt 5, её переименовали в muletimedia

```
QT += multimedia
```